# Multiple JLabel doesn't print on screen

Tags: java, jlabel

I want to print multiple label according to the number(no string allowed) you wrote in a text field first. I want it to be dynamical. I want it to change every time you type something in the text field.

So far it can read if it's a number or a string and throw exception if the text doesn't match the requirement.

I've try multiple thing to print multiple Jlabel on the screen, but it didn't work so far.

Here's the code: can you help me?

The main window class

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {
private MainPanel mp = new MainPanel();
public MainWindow()
{
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setTitle("Calculateur sur 100");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(200, 400);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setContentPane(mp);

}}
```

The mainPanel class

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, MouseListener, KeyListener {

private JTextField tI = new JTextField("Pourcentage");
private JOptionPane jop3 = new JOptionPane();

public MainPanel()
{
    this.add(tI);
    tI.addKeyListener(this);
    tI.addMouseListener(this);


}

//Mathematic calculation
private double onHundred(int tot, int now)
{

    return (tot / 100) * now;
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        boolean ok = true;
        try
        {
            int numbs = Integer.parseInt(tI.getText());
        }
        catch(Exception s)
        {
            tI.setText("");
            jop3.showMessageDialog(null, "Veuillez entrer seulement des chiffres", "Erreur", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            ok = false;
        }
        if(ok)
        {
            System.out.print("Supposed to print");
            JLabel[] label = new JLabel[Integer.parseInt(tI.getText())];
            for(int i = Integer.parseInt(tI.getText()); i <= 0; i--)
            {
                label[i] = new JLabel(i + " = " + Math.ceil(onHundred(Integer.parseInt(tI.getText()), i)));
                label[i].setVisible(true);
                this.add(label[i]);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: This doesn't compile, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (and don't post your full code, just the relevant parts that we can copy-paste and run).

Comment: It's more complete now

Comment: Very good. Two questions: (1) Is there a limit to the number of labels you want to allow to display? If the user pastes `99999999999` you're in trouble. (2) What layout do you want? A grid with X columns that dynamically adds rows? As it is, the labels are all added in 1 row and it won't take many of them to flow out of the screen.

Comment: You're right, iI did'nt thought of a user putting a crazy number. I think I would limit to 150. Second, I don't know how grid works yet. I guess it works like in **Qt**. Anyway, both way I would'nt know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `MainWindow` class should look something like this:

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    private MainPanel mp = new MainPanel();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new MainWindow();
    }

    public MainWindow() {

        setContentPane(mp);
        setTitle("Calculateur sur 100");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Note the order: `setContentPane` then `pack` then `setVisible`. `pack` replaces `setSize` as it determines the preferred size of the window based on its components.

I modified your `MainPanel` class:

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel {

    private JTextField tI = new JTextField("Pourcentage");
    JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel();

    public MainPanel() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        tI.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new MyDocumentListener());
        add(tI, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(labelPanel);
    }

    private int check() {

        int numL;
        try {
            numL = Integer.parseInt(tI.getText());
        } catch (NumberFormatException exc) {
            return 0;
        }
        return numL > 100? 100 : numL;
    }

    private void update(int numL) {

        labelPanel.removeAll();
        for (int i = 0; i < numL; i++)
            labelPanel.add(new JLabel(String.valueOf(i+1)));

        JFrame mainWindow = ((JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this));
        mainWindow.pack();
        mainWindow.repaint();
    }

    class MyDocumentListener implements DocumentListener {

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

            update(check());
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

            update(check());
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

- The main panel has the text field separately from another panel which updates dynamically to contain the labels.
- The text field uses a `DocumentListener` instead of a `KeyListener` to listen to changes in its contents. This is the correct approach for many reasons I will not get into here unless really necessary.
- Whenever the text changes, a `check` method verifies that the input is a number. If it's not it returns 0. If it's more than 100 it returns 100. You can change this behavior as you need.
- The value from `check` is passed to `update` which clears all the previous labels and reconstructs them. (You can do a bit of optimization here if you want by keeping labels in memory but not displaying them. If the cap is 100 as in my example this won't be noticeable.). The main frame then recalculates the space it needs for all the labels and then repaints.
- The labels appear next to each other because the default layout for `JPanel` is `FlowLayout`. You can change this as needed.

Comment: I've tried your code(modified it for my need) and I don't get the "update" part. It does'nt update every time I type something in. This is why in the first place I used `KeyListener`.

Comment: @Chax If you copy-paste my code does it work for you? If so, your modification broke it and you will need to understand why.

Comment: @Chax I rechecked and it works. Make sure you clean and build the project separately. When you type a number into the text field, does it now show labels with numbers? Do you get any error?

Comment: I copied the exact code you gave me. It doesn't give me an error. There's no label printing.

Comment: @Chax Then something is wrong with your setup. I checked on another computer and it works, try to do so as well. When you type "12" into the text fields you should see labels numbered 1 through 12.

Comment: I've put your code in a brand new project and it worked. There is probably something I did't cleaned correctly. Now I'm gonna find where i fuc***d up and try to learn from it. Many thanks.

Comment: Is it normal that i can't divide the number that the check method return?

Comment: @Chax What is "can't"? It returns an `int` - you can divide it. If it's `0` you get an exception.

Comment: There is always an exception raised.

Comment: @Chax Then no. The method returns an `int` which can be positive, then dividing it will not give an exception.

Comment: `    private int onHundred(int a, int b)
    {
     return (a / b) * 100;
    }`

That's my function. As **a** I pass _i_ from the loop and as **b** I tried _numL_ and _check()_. With both of them I get 0.

Comment: @Chax If you divide by 0 you get an error, that's all there is to it. Why the function returns 0 is something you need to check with a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

First - you have `Integer.parseInt(tI.getText())` a number of times within the same `keyReleased` function. When you have done the first check to assign it to `int numbs`, then use `numbs` from then on, instead of referring back to `tI.getText()`. Theoretically the user input can change while you are processing your array, which will cause runtime exceptions or undesired results. Hint - declare `numbs` directly under `ok`.

Second - after you add controls programmatically, you need to `invalidate` the control on to which you are adding them, ie your `MainPanel`. The `invalidate` directive tells the control that it is not drawn correctly and needs to be repainted (do this at the completion of your loop).  Look through the documentation for JPanel for `invalidate` and `paint`.